# Why is my boost converter not working on breadboard but works in LTspice

Tags: buck-boost

Here is my diagram in LTspice.
[image]

And the wave should look like this in the simulation.
I have tried to use the same model for my spice simulation in order top make it as similar as my breadboard circuit.

[image]

The output should be around 9.3V
However, the one I build on breadboard can only output 5.187V

The following is the picture I took with my smartphone.

[image]

[image]

**Update**

After changing the diode to BAT42 (https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bat42.pdf), I found I connected the wrong wires in BJT transistor.

However, I got a new problem now. One is Vcontrol (see schematics above) and the other is Vout (see schematics above) in my oscillosocpe. Vout is  alternating between 12 volts and 0 despite of frequency.

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145238/discussion-on-question-by-kile-why-is-my-boost-converter-not-working-on-breadboa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need higher frequency or larger capacitor to smooth it out. Signal transistor is also not suitable for switching power.